An war movie about undercover troops destroying enemy base by attaching special signs for missile
I think the name of the movie was blah blah - man. paint man? idk... imdb won't come up with the title paint man.
The main character was an African-american soldier who is way better in attaching the missile signs than the other team members. At first he didn't go well with the other members. The main story was destroying the factory? by attaching the missile signals. The missile sign was something you could attach to the wall or etc. and the missile would follow and target that sign.
Can anyone please tell me the title? :) Language was English. I think the background was either USA or UK. I guess it was a movie released after year 2000.

Welcome to the site, can you add some more details, what sort of signs were they? When did you watch the film? Is it in English?

Not much to go on, but it could be "The Marksman" with Wesley Snipes from 2005
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marksman
I saw it years ago, it was pretty forgettable.  The basic plot is that Wesley Snipes is a soldier who has to mark a nuclear reactor for destruction.  The way he does this is to use a laser designator to point at the target (marking the target or 'painting the target'). The missle can detect and home in on this laser and will destroy whatever the laser points at.
(This is actually a fairly common way of destroying targets.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_designator)
IIRC His team gets attached to another team, and they don't get on well
